# FTP file transfer, loop through a directory and copy old files

Tags: bash, ftp

I would like to move files older than 30 days and copy them into a remote FTP server.

I've already written this script, that is able to connect via FTP.

Usually, to move files, I would run this line:

```
find ./logs/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv {} destination \;
```

The problem is FTP doesn't recognize that command. So I think I should loop through files and move only those that are older than 30 days. But I'm not an expert in bash.

Can anyone help me please?

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=xxx             #This is the FTP servers host or IP address.
USER=xxx                     #This is the FTP user that has access to the server.
PASS=xxx              #This is the password for the FTP user.

# Call 1. Uses the ftp command with the -inv switches. 
#-i turns off interactive prompting. 
#-n Restrains FTP from attempting the auto-login feature. 
#-v enables verbose and progress. 

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF

# Call 2. Here the login credentials are supplied by calling the variables.

user $USER $PASS

pass

# Call 3. I change to the directory where I want to put or get
cd /

# Call4.  Here I will tell FTP to put or get the file.
find ./logs/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec echo {} \;
#put files older than 30 days

# End FTP Connection
bye

EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use shell commands (like `find`) in an `ftp` script.

Though you can use a shell script to generate the `ftp` script.

```
echo open $HOST > ftp.txt
echo user $USER $PASS >> ftp.txt
find ./logs/ -type f -mtime +30 -printf "put logs/%f %f\n" >> ftp.txt
echo bye >> ftp.txt

ftp < ftp.txt
```

The above code will generate file `ftp.txt` with commands and pass that to `ftp`. The generated `ftp.txt` will look like:

```
open host
user user pass
put logs/first.log first.log
put logs/second.log second.log
put logs/third.log third.log
...
bye
```

Comment: Hey @martin, I want to copy files into the FTP. So find command should executes "mv {} ...". I'll try, but I didn't understand this solution. Why is different from mine? thanks

Comment: *"copy files into the FTP"*: That's "upload" right? For upload, there's `put` command. There's no `mv` command in `ftp`. Why is different: Because your solution cannot work, all the code between `<< EOF` and `EOF` is `ftp` script. And there's no `find` command in `ftp`. My solution uses shell commands (including `find`) to generate an `ftp.txt` file with all commands.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more explanation.

Comment: Ok, I understood. It's a good solution. And it works! One additional question: It seems the remote FTP server does not accept "put" (I've updated the first post). What do you think?

Comment: So please remote the part on "passive" mode form your post. It's irrelevant to the titular question.

Comment: One more problem: if I don't append the remote filename after the "put" command, script will try to execute something like this: "put /localpath/file" (AND /localpath doesn't exist on remote server). This is beacause "find" returns files with path. How can I build a command like "put /localfile/file file" ?

Comment: Again, see the update answer.

Comment: You need to run the batch script with `ftp -n < ftp.txt`. Otherwise, it will default the user name.